# return any value larger than three for columns with similar names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
df_col1 df_col2 df_col3 df_col4 id name
3          4      5        2     1  a
2          3      2        1     2  d
2          1      1        2     3  x
```

This dataframe is very large

if I want to return any value with a column name df_col larger than 3, is there anyway I can make the code run faster. My current code is

```
df.filter(like='df_') > 3
```

this runs very slow, is it possible to make it faster?

PS: I want to get the value > 3 not True or False

Comment: you want to get the columns with value > 3 ?

Comment: How looks expected ouput? name `a` or something else?

Comment: `PS: I want to get the value > 3 not True or False` - What it is?

Comment: For example, if the value is 4, return 4, if the value is 5, return 5

Comment: I think in sample data, what is ouput?

Comment: Or `df_col2 df_col3` ?

Comment: or `df_col4` because `4>3` ?

Comment: Or values `4,5` because `>3`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
In [616]: cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('df_')]

In [617]: df[cols].gt(3)
Out[617]: 
   df_col1  df_col2  df_col3  df_col4
0    False     True     True    False
1    False    False    False    False
2    False    False    False    False
```

Comment: This won't be any faster than what he has already tried, in fact it will probably be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
a = np.unique(df.filter(like='df_'))
print (a)
[1 2 3 4 5]

v = a[a > 3].tolist()
print (v)
[4, 5]
```